# Need to extract the data based on delimiter and map to data frame in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need to extract the data with `~~` delimiter and map accordingly to the required columns.

But the output somehow is random and getting wrong results/mappings.
How can we achieve this using pyspark?

Sample Date:
MESSAGE from Dataframe column

```
{5:~~:2016:ABCDEF123~~:2323:002~~:2016:567~~::555:~~XXABC~~:2016:123~~:555:~~YYYYY~~-}
{5:~~:2016:DEF~~:2323:009~~:2016:666~~::555:~~ZZZZ~~:2016:788~~:555:~~DDDDD~~:2016:5013~~:555:~~TTTTTTTT~~-}
```

Expected Data Frame Output:

```
PARENT_REF|PARENT_TXN||CHILD_REF|_CHILD_ORG

ABCDEF123|002|567|XXABC

ABCDEF123|002|123|YYYYY

DEF|009|666|ZZZZ

DEF|009|788|DDDDD

DEF|009|5013|TTTTTTTT
```

First 2016 is PARENT_REF.
First 2323 is Parent TXN.
Subsequent 2016 is child Ref.
Susequent 555 is Child org.

Note - Child records can vary for a parent Record

Code Snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2=df1.select("MESSAGE")

df3=df2.withColumn("PARENT_REF",F.regexp_extract(F.col('MESSAGE'),'\{5:*:.*:2016:(.*?)~~:"',1))
        .withColumn("PARENT_TXN",F.regexp_extract(F.col('MESSAGE'),'\{5:*:.*:2323:(.*?)~~:"',1))
        .withColumn("CHILD_REF",F.regexp_extract(F.col('MESSAGE'),'\{5:*:.*:2016:(.*?)~~:"',1))
        .withColumn("CHILD_ORG",F.regexp_extract(F.col('MESSAGE'),'\{5:*:.*:555:(.*?)~~:"',1))

df3.show()
```

Comment: Can anyone help on this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a correct regex

###### Sample data

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('{5:~~:2016:ABCDEF123~~:2323:002~~:2016:567~~::555:~~XXABC~~:2016:123~~:555:~~YYYYY~~-}',),
    ('{5:~~:2016:DEF~~:2323:009~~:2016:666~~::555:~~ZZZZ~~:2016:788~~:555:~~DDDDD~~:2016:5013~~:555:~~TTTTTTTT~~-}',),
], ['message'])

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|message                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{5:~~:2016:ABCDEF123~~:2323:002~~:2016:567~~::555:~~XXABC~~:2016:123~~:555:~~YYYYY~~-}                      |
|{5:~~:2016:DEF~~:2323:009~~:2016:666~~::555:~~ZZZZ~~:2016:788~~:555:~~DDDDD~~:2016:5013~~:555:~~TTTTTTTT~~-}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

###### Transformation

```py
(df
    .withColumn('parent_ref',F.regexp_extract(F.col('message'), '\{5:~~:2016:([^~]+)~~:2323:([^~]+)~~([^-]+)-}', 1))
    .withColumn('parent_txn',F.regexp_extract(F.col('message'), '\{5:~~:2016:([^~]+)~~:2323:([^~]+)~~([^-]+)-}', 2))
    .withColumn('children',  F.regexp_extract(F.col('message'), '\{5:~~:2016:([^~]+)~~:2323:([^~]+)~~([^-]+)-}', 3))
    .withColumn('child',  F.explode(F.split('children', ':2016:')))
    .where(F.col('child') != '')
    .withColumn('child_ref', F.regexp_extract(F.col('child'), '^([^~]+)', 1))
    .withColumn('child_org', F.regexp_extract(F.col('child'), '~~([^~]+)~~$', 1))
    .drop('message', 'children', 'child')
    .show(10, False)
)

+----------+----------+---------+---------+
|parent_ref|parent_txn|child_ref|child_org|
+----------+----------+---------+---------+
|ABCDEF123 |002       |567      |XXABC    |
|ABCDEF123 |002       |123      |YYYYY    |
|DEF       |009       |666      |ZZZZ     |
|DEF       |009       |788      |DDDDD    |
|DEF       |009       |5013     |TTTTTTTT |
+----------+----------+---------+---------+
```